# Необходимо наполовину размыть блок

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Есть таблица с элементами последний из которых наполовину размыт, вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
можно ли сделать подобный эффект средствами css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте добиться желаемого результата с помощью комбинации свойства `opacity` и свойства `background: linear-gradient()`

```css
body {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-3.jpg');
  max-width: 600px;
}

div {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.last {
  background: linear-gradient(0, transparent, #fff);
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Content
</div>
<div class="last">
  Content
</div>
```